# nodejs how to dynamically manipulate your MongoDB aggregate in your controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very loooong aggregate in my nodejs controller:

```
agentSaleModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: 
            [{ 
                _id: { $in: req.body.propertyID },
                active : true
            }]
        }
    }, etc....
```

And it works great when I got elements in my req.body.propertyID
like ["property01","property02"] etc...

My problem is that I also want the aggregate to work when there are nothing in req.body.propertyID. (when its blank) - and then get all records.

This does not work:

```
agentSaleModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: 
            [{ 
                _id: { $in: '' },
                active : true
            }]
        }
    }, etc....
```

So rather than doing an "if" with two huge sets of almost identical code:

```
if (req.body.propertyID) {
   ...the entire aggregate... 
} else {
   ...the entire aggregate minus the _id: { $in: req.body.propertyID },... 
}
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?

**SOLUTION!! Thanks to FluffyNights :)**

```
if (req.body.propertyID!='') {
    var matchStr = { 
        $match: {
            $and: 
            [{ 
                _id: { $in: req.body.propertyID },
                active : true
            }]
        }
    }
} else {
    var matchStr = { 
        $match: {
                active : true
        }
    }
}
agentSaleModel.aggregate([ matchStr, etc..... (rest of pipeline)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
let query = [
    {
        $match: {
            $and: 
            [{ 
                active : true
            }]
        }
    }];
if(req.body.propertyID) {
   query[0]["$match"]["$and"][0]["_id"] = { $in: req.body.propertyID };
}
agentSaleModel.aggregate(query, ...)
```

you could also use regex, like:

```
if(!req.body.properyID){
    req.body.propertyID = [ ".*" ];
}
agentSaleModel.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $and: 
        [{ 
            _id: { $in: req.body.propertyID },
            active : true
        }]
    }
}, etc....
```

however, this might get slow.
Im not sure if passing null to $in would work the way you want, you could try it though.

Comment: YES!!!  Your suggestion actually worked! - Let me post my final solution in the question so you can see it.  Thank you so much.  I didnt really understand that you could build the object and then just inject it into the big aggregate :)

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to construct query before running it.

For example.

`var query = req.body.propertyID ? { $and: [{_id: { $in: req.body.propertyID }, active : true}]} : {active : true}`

```
agentSaleModel.aggregate([
{
   $match: query
}, etc....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That one worked too, and is very simple and elegant.  Thanks Mykola!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an inline solution using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
$match: {
  $and: [
    {
      _id: { [ req.body.propertyID ? '$in' : '$exists' ] : req.body.propertyID || true },
      active: true,
    },
  ],
}
```

When `req.body.propertyID` exists, the query becomes:

```
_id : { $in : req.body.propertyID }
```

If not:

```
_id : { $exists : true }
```

**EDIT**: this will also allow `req.body.propertyID` to equal `"ALL"` if you explicitly want to match all documents:

```
let selectAll = ! req.body.propertyID || req.body.propertyID === 'ALL';
const query = {
  $match: {
    $and: [
      {
        _id: { [ selectAll ? '$exists' : '$in' ] : selectAll || req.body.propertyID },
        active: true,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Ok Robertklep - thats gotta be the most easy simple solution yet :-)  Thanks!

Comment: I got a question for the req.body.propertyID || true.  What if I have something like `if (req.body.propertyID != 'ALL' && req.body.propertyID != '')` how would you write that in your one-liner?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard see edit. You _can_ place all of that in a one-liner, but it wouldn't be very clear, so I'd suggest using a separate boolean variable.